# install4j code signing with sha256 digest

Tags: install4j

Microsoft announced that starting from January 1, 2016, software signed with certificates which use SHA-1 algorithm will no longer be treated as digitally signed. It will display warnings when installing such software.

Now, how do I tell install4j to use sha256 instead of default sha1? My certificate is capable of doing it but so far everything comes out singed with sha1. For now I tried manually signing the exes with "/fd sha256" option in signtool, it works OK. So how do we make install4j for doing the same during build time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 6.0.4, you can add a compiler variable

```
sys.ext.install4j.winDigest
```

with a value

```
SHA-2
```

to change the algorithm. We will change the default in the next release.

Comment: @Ingo Kegel, does that mean that install4j does not support sha-2 before version 6.0.4?  We are still on 5.1.12 and we're about to release a new version of our app with sha-2 - does that mean we have to upgrade install4j in order to use our sha-2 cert?

Comment: That is correct, SHA-2 is supported by default since install4j 6.1. You can do external signing if you don't want to upgrade, see the "Executable processing" step of the media file wizard.